# convert YYYYMMDD string to a valid date in Go

Tags: go

I want to convert a string `"20101011"` to a valid date (`2010-10-11`), but could not figure our how to do it.

I tried:

```
now := time.Now()
date := now.Format("20101011")
```

and

```
date, _ := time.Parse("20101011", "20101011")
```

neither one worked.

Answer (score 13):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [Constants](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)
>
> ```
> const (
>         ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
>         UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
>         RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
>         RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
>         RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
>         RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
>         RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
>         RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
>         RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
>         RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
>         Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
>         // Handy time stamps.
>         Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
>         StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
>         StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
>         StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
> )
> ```
>
> These are predefined layouts for use in Time.Format and Time.Parse.
>   The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006`
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference
>   time can be thought of as
>
> ```
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
> ```
>
> To define your own format, write down what the reference time would
>   look like formatted your way; see the values of constants like ANSIC,
>   StampMicro or Kitchen for examples. The model is to demonstrate what
>   the reference time looks like so that the Format and Parse methods can
>   apply the same transformation to a general time value.

Use the `time` format string `"20060102"` for `YYYYMMDD`. Use the `time` format string `"2006-01-02"` for `YYYY-MM-DD`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(now)
    date := now.Format("20060102")
    fmt.Println(date)
    date = now.Format("2006-01-02")
    fmt.Println(date)
    date2, err := time.Parse("20060102", "20101011")
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(date2)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
20091110
2009-11-10
2010-10-11 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
dateStr := "20210131"                           // date in 'String' data type
dateValue, _ := time.Parse("20060102", dateStr) // convert 'String' to 'Time' data type
fmt.Println(dateValue)                          // output: 2021-01-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
dateStr = dateValue.Format("2006-01-02")       // Format return a 'string' in your specified layout (YYYY-MM-DD)
fmt.Println(dateStr)                           // Output: 2021-01-31
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind another library, Google's [`civil` package](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go@v0.109.0/civil#ParseDate) has a nice `ParseDate()` which skips the interim `time.Time` conversion. It can be used like so:

```golang
func ParseDate(s string) (Date, error) {
    date, err := civil.ParseDate(s)
    return Date{date}, err
}
```